# Sharepoint Ribbon for view item form going full option

Tags: web-part, ribbon, custom-form, list-item

I have a view item form which contains a custom WebPart for displaying that item. I have no issue with that but the ribbon for the display form looks weird: It contains lots of options that don't apply for the item.

Here is what I mean:

View tab:

[image]

Page tab:

[image]

I am doing no customization at all to the ribbon; it just appears like that.

What might trigger this?

Comment: I guess that just comes from the base your webpart is build on. Kind of out-of-the-box features with this type of webpart. Did you build this custom WebPart by using a blank one and adding functionality? Did you try different ootb webParts? Did they look different?

Comment: @Shegit Brahm : I see where you are going... I'm extending a DataFormWebPart; If I use a classic ListFormWebPart for example (can't extend that as it's sealed) I get a normal ribbon. I guess ListFormWebPart is doing something to the ribbon. Will have to check that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to remove the buttons from the WebPart. I've stuck this in the WebPart:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            Ribbon currentRibbon = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            foreach (string rid in litsOfRibbonIdsToExclude)
            {
                currentRibbon.TrimById(rid);
            }
}
```

with `litsOfRibbonIdsToExclude` an array with "Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.ApproveReject", "Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.CheckIn", 
                    "Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.CheckOut", ......