# Item Display Form showing View + Page tab in Ribbon while other pages have only View

Tags: web-part, ribbon, custom-form, web-part-page, display-form

I have a list with [a display form for which I have specified a different rendering WebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544142.aspx): DataFormWebPart as opposed to the default ListFormWebPart.

This [caused some issues with the Ribbon](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29030/sharepoint-ribbon-for-view-item-form-going-full-option). I managed to figure out what was going on but now I have another issue which can be seen in the images of that post.

**I have a Page tab in the display form.** All other display forms don't have it. There is just a View tab.

It's possible that again the ListFormWebPart is doing something different and removes the Page tab, but I just want to be sure (so as to not head on a wrong path and tear the ListFormWebPart apart to see what's going on for nothing).

Is the Page tab controlled by certain WebParts? Or another way of putting it: in what conditions does the Page tab appear on a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out if the WebPart is doing something, but I managed to remove the tab with `currentRibbon.TrimById("Ribbon.WebPartPage")` just like in the other question of mine.